# SQL Server on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: 23.10, sql

I just wondering if there's anyways to use SQL server on Ubuntu 23.10? I've read the Install SQL Server for Linux by Microsoft and it said that only Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 were supported. I don't want to boot back to Windows everytime just to use SQL. I'm currently learning SQL so if there's any alternatives using SQL on Ubuntu 23.10, can you recommend me pls?
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to have a database running on your machine to learn SQL then I recommend using Docker and spinning up an image with the database you want. PostgreSQL is a good alternative with great Docker documentation, but there is also images for SQL Server.

Installing Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Getting PostgreSQL image and running it in docker: https://www.baeldung.com/ops/postgresql-docker-setup